# What does it mean that as compared to iterator, generators gives back an implicit iterable sequence?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I am new to programming and am facing trouble with a conceptual question.

It was said in class that, a generator is used to break up the execution. Secondly, it was also said that "When using generators, we perform lazy evaluation, that produces an implicit iterable sequence."

I don't understand this concept of why is it "lazy evaluation". And what does it mean to have an implicit iterable sequence? Isn't that what iterators are used for?

Most online websites just spoke about the difference between iterators and generators, but I don't understand what it could possibly mean to break up the execution. Since we can only use a generator within the execution process. Does this mean it works like a return statement?​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the generator example below:

```
# Lazy evaluation. Instead of an "instant" complete result
# you get an iterator that you can execute in steps to get
# all results, one by one.

# This can be useful to save memory if the results are big,
# or to advance code execution in steps, because the generator
# remembers state between next() calls
def get_three_ints(start=0):
    for next_int in range(start, start+3):
        print("I'm running!") # advance a little more in code
        yield next_int # suspend execution here. Wait for
                       # another next() # while returning
                       # next_int


gen = get_three_ints(5) # gen is a generator function because of yield
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))

try:
    print(next(gen)) # raises StopIteration (the iterator was consumed)
except StopIteration:
    print("Got a StopIteration.\n")

# Another generator. A generator is implicitely iterable.
gen = get_three_ints(10)
for i in gen:
    print(i)

# This is because both an __iter__ and __next__ special methods
# were created in your generator object just by using the keyword yield
print()
print(type(gen),'\n')

gen_attrs = dir(gen)
print('__iter__' in gen_attrs)
print('__next__' in gen_attrs)

# The "opposite" of this is creating a function that executes at once
# and returns the complete result
def get_three_ints_now(start=0):
    return list(range(start, start+3))

print()
print(get_three_ints_now(20))

# Output:

I'm running!
5
I'm running!
6
I'm running!
7
Got a StopIteration.

I'm running!
10
I'm running!
11
I'm running!
12

<class 'generator'> 

True
True

[20, 21, 22]
```